# Create a local DB and import csv or excel file

Tags: sql, t-sql, import, sql-server-2008-r2

Due to circumstances beyond my control, I'm currently not able to create a table on one of my company's databases, and I got a project where I need to break down and get stats from a large data file.  I can open it in Excel, but its not very happy about it.  What I'd like to be able to do is create a local database where I could use the import wizard to import an excel file to a new table.  Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: SQL server has a free express edition of their database http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx . It probably has a cumulative data limit though (Oracle express does, I don't know much about sql server express).

Comment: I would recommend using Express as well and just install it locally. Here's a **[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)** to a chart showing the differences between editions.

Comment: If this is not permanent task you can download and install full-featured SQL Server trial. You have 180 days for exploring the newest product along with solving your problem.

Comment: @Brian DeMilia - That worked like a charm.  If you want to make it an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: @Jon just pasted it as an answer, glad it worked out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server has a free express edition of their database http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx. It probably has a cumulative data limit though (Oracle express does, I don't know much about sql server express).